# Pull Requests in CodeCommit

Tags: continuous-integration, pull-request, aws-codecommit

Is there a similar concept or workaround for Pull Requests inside AWS CodeCommit? I'm trying to implement CI using a CodeCommit repository and help us avoid broken head in our repository (master branch should always compile and run all tests successfully).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeCommit now supports Pull Requests:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/aws-codecommit-supports-pull-requests/

Answer (score 23):

Such a feature does not exist, at least yet. But I have passed your feature request to the team for further review and consideration. Your feedback is very much appreciated.

Paige@AWS

Comment: Good to know. Is there a recommended practice that we can use for now?

Comment: This is now inaccurate. CodeCommit now supports Pull Requests: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/aws-codecommit-supports-pull-requests/

Answer (score 1):

Still no such feature, but we can always follow some best practices for Git itself. Things like making changes in branches and only merge it to master after it passed unit tests and code review. [This link](http://blog.beanbaginc.com/2015/01/26/an-effective-rbtools-workflow-for-git/) provides some more details. It discussion was based on the ReviewBoard tool but you don't have to use it to apply the same approach for code review.